# How Sql-Server service can be activated in local application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I am using a local database in a typical `WPF` application. I tried to run that for debugging but it did not work and gave me the following error:

> <2016-11-23T17:59:19.1888435+03:30
>     The underlying provider failed on Open.
>     at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func 1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass47 1.<ExecuteFunction>b__45()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func 1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>      at FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent.EngineEntities.SignIn(String mail, String password) in c:\Users\Media Depp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\NewProjects\SeyyedAmir\FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent\FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent\EngineModel.Context.cs:line 61
>      at FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent.DataAccess.SearchUSerDA(String name, String pass) in c:\Users\Media Depp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\NewProjects\SeyyedAmir\FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent\FirstAttemptForFillingOutTheContent\DataAccess.cs:line 140
>     EntityFramework
>     A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

After searching I figured out that the database service of my `OS` is not active:
[image: Sql Service]

I activate it manually and the program worked properly. How an I activate the service in `C#` code itself if the service was not activated. I have looked posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526940/sql-server-services-can-they-be-started-automatically) but I need some `C#` code to do that.

Comment: It seems you hosted sqlserver on your local machine,some times service may not start,due to settings like automatic start,not being enabled.some times your laptop may be rebooted multiple times,I don't see any issue once SQL is hosted

Comment: @TheGameiswar yes, sometimes the service does not start automatically and in such cases my application does not work. I wan to start it from my own application. I did not understand you did not understand which part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command line prompt and use the following:

`NET START MSSQLSERVER` Starts SQL Server as a service.

or

`NET START MSSQL$instancename` Starts SQL Server as a service, where instancename is the actual name of the database server instance.

Two ways in C#:

```
var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MyService", "MyRemoteMachine");
sc.Start();
sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
sc.Stop();
sc.WaitForStatus(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
```

or

```
 sc <server> start [service name]
 sc <server> stop [service name]
```

Use `sc <server> query | find "SERVICE_NAME"`

to get a list of service names.

The option `<server>` has the form `\\ServerName`

Example

`sc \\MyServer stop schedule` will stop the Scheduler service.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to that in `C#`?